# Button to upload integer to Firebase database IOS

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

When a button is pressed, I need to save the rating of the item in the database. While my slider works and my variable 'currentValue' works, I have unable to get a rating submitted to the database though as it crashes the app. If I've made a simple mistake, definitely let me know.

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!

@IBOutlet weak var sliderLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var verticalSlider: UISlider!

       {
            didSet{
                verticalSlider.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-M_PI_2))

            }
    }

@IBAction func verticalSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        var currentValue = Int(sender.value);

        sliderLabel?.text = "\(currentValue)"

}


@IBAction func checkmarkButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {


    let img:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 180, width: 250, height: 320))

    let randomImage = arc4random()

    if (randomImage % 4 == 0) {
        img.image = UIImage(named: "hero.jpg")
    } else if (randomImage % 3 == 1) {
        img.image = UIImage(named: "hillary.jpg")
    } else {
        img.image = UIImage(named: "thistimeisdifferent.png")

    **self.ref.child(uuid).child("Book Info").child("Book Title").child("Slider Value").setValue(currentValue)**

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not able to give you the exact answer to fix this without seeing more of your project, I can suggest a few things.

First, make sure that all of your @IBOutlets and @IBActions are connected.  This will for sure cause a crash if these objects and actions are not connected.  To troubleshoot this, comment out your code and set a breakpoint on your actions and just see if you are able to interact with your outlets and get to your actions.

Second, validate the execution of your code to make sure that you are working with safe data.  For example,

```
@IBAction func verticalSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    // This will allow a safer way to interact with you data
    if let currentValue = sender.value as? Int {
        sliderLabel?.text = "\(currentValue)"
    }
}

@IBAction func checkmarkButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {


    let img:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 180, width: 250, height: 320))
    self.view.addSubview(img)

    guard img != nil else {
        return
    }

    let randomImage = arc4random()

    if (randomImage % 4 == 0) {
        img.image = UIImage(named: "hero.jpg")
    } else if (randomImage % 3 == 1) {
        img.image = UIImage(named: "hillary.jpg")
    } else {
        img.image = UIImage(named: "thistimeisdifferent.png")

        guard let currentVal = currentValue, 
              currentVal.characters.count > 0 else {
            return
        }
        self.ref.child(uuid).child("Book Info").child("Book Title").child("Slider Value").setValue(currentVal)

    }
```

Validating the data you are working with each step of the way should allow you to determine if your issue is the data you are inserting into FireBase, your outlets, or your application logic.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks much for that. I'm still working on this but hopefully it will work.